# Under Mac OS Yosemite in Android Studio floating mode windows constantly jump back to the monitor with the primary window

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I haven't found an answer, nor question about this on Stackoverflow, so I post it here. I even managed to solve it though, so here are the details and the solution:

**Details:**
2 monitors, Android Studio opened on the first one. You put a tab/view into floating mode and move to the 2nd monitor. When you click back on the 1st monitor, then click to 2nd monitor, the tab/view you moved to the 2nd monitor automatically moves back to the 1st. It's very annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

As I found here (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77779),
the solution is to install this (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) package, which is the legacy java 6 runtime.

Comment: Turned out, that a Yosemite->El Capitan update removes the legacy 1.6 java jdk, so after you update to El Capitan, you have to download the java 1.6 jdk again, install and restart.